# Is using #import <AppTrackingTransparency/AppTrackingTransparency.h> the same as linking the AppTrackingTransparency.framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, apptrackingtransparency

With the ever-confusing AppTrackingTransparency setup, I have been simply adding

```
Privacy - Tracking Usage Description - My description
```

To the .plist file, as well as using

```
#import <AppTrackingTransparency/AppTrackingTransparency.h>
```

in my `AppDelegate.h` file.

As well as calling;

```
if (@available(iOS 14, *)) {
            [ATTrackingManager requestTrackingAuthorizationWithCompletionHandler:^(ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatus status) {
                switch (status) {
                    case ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
                        NSLog(@"ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusAuthorized");
                        
                        break;
                    case ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusDenied:
                       
                        NSLog(@"ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusDenied");
                        break;
                    case ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
                        
                        NSLog(@"ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusRestricted");
                        break;
                    case ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
                        
                        NSLog(@"ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined");
                        break;
                }
            }];
        } else {
           
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    
}
```

All has been OK with regards to compiling, and even submitting the apps, however I have now realised I have not been importing the `AppTrackingTransparency.framework` inside the 'Build Phases' section of Xcode.

Should I be adding this framework inside the build phases as well, is it a problem that I have not done it so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can successfully get your app compiled, you surely already link your app with your `AppTrackingTransparency.framework` in some way.

Otherwise, you will see error message from Xcode like screenshot below:

[image: Xcode linking error of AppTrackingTransparency.framework]

Do you use CocoaPods, Carthage or Swift Package Manager? Maybe one of your package link to `AppTrackingTransparency.framework`.